# Helmholtz equation with moving boundary in the plane

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, eigenfunctions

Let us assume we have a unit disk $D\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ s.t. $\vec{0}\in D$. To obtain the eigenfrequencies and eigenmodes (or eigenvalues and -functions if you  like) we must solve $\Delta \psi + \lambda^2 \psi = 0$ with appropriate boundary conditions.

This can be done analytically using the ansatz $\psi(r,\phi)=R(r)\Phi(\phi)$ to obtain Bessel's equation. After a long but simple derivation one obtains the roots of Bessel's functions of the first kind as eigenvalues.

Here's my problem then:

Assuming we start to rotate the disk in the plane around the origin will result in a moving boundary.

Can we still determine the eigenvalues of the unit disc analytically?

I know that one can obtain the eigenvalues employing coordinate transformations which will modify the equation, transforming it into a coordinate frame where the boundary is at rest and hence Dirichlet conditions may be used. But I'm interested specifically in an analytic solution where the differential equation is **not** modified.

Does such a solution exist?

Comment: If the equation itself doesn't depend on time, then the eigenvalues remain the same. The final solution just has time as a parameter

Comment: I can argue, that the eigenvalues should remain the same from a physical point of view (changing how I look at the system, not the system itself). I need either a math. proof of identity of EV or a way to derive an explicit expression of the EV for moving boundary.

Comment: Apply separation of variables: $\psi = R(r)\Phi(\phi)T(t)$. If you plug this in the original equation, the time parts would all cancel out, and you get same equations for $R(r)$ and $\Phi(\phi)$ as before. The only thing that changes is the coefficients in the series solution would be dependent on $t$